# Perl map function output assigned to variable

Tags: perl, dictionary

I'd like to concatenate the output of the `map` function in Perl to a string variable.   However, if I try this:

```
$body .= map {"$_\n"} sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

The value of $body equals 3 instead of the expected

```
user1
user2
user3
```

If I do:

```
print map {"$_\n"} sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

it gives me what I want.

So how can I mimic the print map functionality and assign it to the body variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is used to transform a list into another list, so that's what it returns. This works with `print` because the `print` function takes a list and will output them separated by the value of `$,` (the output field separator.)

If you want to join a list together into a string, you have to use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

```
$body .= join "\n", sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

Comment: That remove the trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

`print` concatenates the array returned by `map`, interleaving items with the value of `$,`.
So, you need this to simulate `print` behavior:

```
$body .= join $,, map {"$_\n"} sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

As long as `print` is your concern, another valid possibility is:

```
print "$_\n" for sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

Or, enabling Perl v5.10 feature `say`, just:

```
say for sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

Extrapolating that for concatenation:

```
$body .= "$_\n" for sort(@{$hash{$server}->{VALID}});
```

Comment: `join '',` is probably more natural than `join $,,`. Few people use `$,`. It's definitely not wrong to use `$,`, but I want to mention this so the OP isn't scared away from the first snippet. Great post, though (+1).